# The Veblen Hierarchy named with uncountable ordinals vs ordinal collapsing functions

Tags: ordinals, transfinite-recursion

I recently came across [Feferman's original $\theta$ function](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Deedlit11/Ordinal_notations_II:_Up_to_the_Bachmann-Howard_ordinal#The_.5C.28.5Ctheta.5C.29_function). I understood the idea behind it. But to get a better idea of the growth I compared it with the Veblen function. When the multi-variable-Veblen-function "ran out". I thought why can't you name the Veblen functions using uncountable ordinals?

So I defined the following extension

## Definition

$f'$ is the function naming the fixed points of $f$.
$f'(\alpha)=\text{the $\alpha^\text{th}$ ordinal in }\{y|y=f(y)\}$

(assuming $\Omega[\beta]=\beta$ and $\beta<\Omega$)
**zero**:                  $\varphi_0(\beta)=\omega^\beta$
**succesor**:         $\varphi_{\alpha+1}=\varphi^{'}_\alpha$
**countable**:      $\varphi_{\alpha}(\beta)[n]=\varphi_{\alpha[n]}(\beta)$
**uncountable**: $\varphi_A(\beta)=\varphi_{A[\beta]}(\beta)$

## Examples

For countable ordinals $\varphi_\alpha$ is the single argument Veblen function.
$\varphi_\Omega(\alpha)=\varphi_\alpha(\alpha)$
$\varphi_{\Omega+1}(\beta)=\Gamma_\beta=\varphi(1,0,\beta)$
$\varphi_{\Omega+1+\alpha}(\beta)=\varphi(1,\alpha,\beta)$
$\varphi_{\Omega\cdot\alpha+1}(\beta)=\varphi(\alpha,0,\beta)$
$\varphi_{\Omega^2+1}(\beta)=\varphi(1,0,0,\beta)$
$\varphi_{\Omega^\alpha+1}(\beta)=\varphi(1,0,\dots,\beta)\text{ α zeros}$
$\varphi_{\Omega^\Omega+1}(0)=\text{LVO}$

## Questions

These examples suggest $\varphi_{\alpha+1}(\beta)=\theta(\alpha,\beta)$

Is this the case? I feel like there is something very similar in both definitions (the next function names the fixed points of the previous).
Can it reach bigger ordinals than The Bachmann–Howard ordinal?
Does $\psi$ get stuck at a certain uncountable ordinals like $\theta$? Which?
Is it practical to extend this further, to ordinals of larger coffanity?

Comment: The 1976 paper [*Normal functions and constructive ordinal notations*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2272243) by Larry W. Miller might be helpful.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I don't have a mathematical background so it's hard to understand.

Comment: I do have a mathematical background, and I also find it hard to understand! However, this is probably one of the most accessible papers on ordinals greater than [$\Gamma_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feferman%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtte_ordinal). Better (I'd forgotten about them) are John Baez's essays --- [Part 1](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/06/29/large-countable-ordinals-part-1/) and [Part 2](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/07/04/large-countable-ordinals-part-2/) and [Part 3](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/large-countable-ordinals-part-3/).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I read those essays yesterday!

Comment: For the uncountable case, you probably wanted something like $\Omega[\beta]=\beta$ and that $\beta<\Omega$ everywhere in your question

Comment: I have been working on extending the Veblen function recently & was wondering if you have made any progress on this? Also, in your system, how would you denote SVO?

Comment: @user820789 Would $\varphi_{\Omega^{\omega}+1}(0)$ be SVO?

Comment: I think the countable subscript case might diverge from Veblen's $\varphi$: $\varphi_\omega(1)=\textrm{sup}\{\varphi_n(\varphi_\omega(0)+1)\,\mid\,n\in\omega\}$ using Veblen's original $\varphi$